# RShiny - how to use multiple inputs (eg select one or more countries from "selectInput" that then determines output to line graph)

Tags: r, shiny

From the following piece of code I want to be able for a user to select one or more countries which then determines the output to a graph.

My original data source is:

```
data_1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/Activity.csv")

df <- data.frame(data_1$REPORT_DATE,data_1$PEOPLE_D_NEW_COUNT,
data_1$PEOPLE_P_NEW_CASES_COUNT,data_1$PEOPLE_D_COUNT,data_1$PEOPLE_P_CASES_COUNT,data_1$COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME)
```

This piece of code below seems to work ok.

```
selectInput(inputId = "country", label = "Country: ", multiple = TRUE,
                       choices = sort(unique(df$COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME)))
```

The bit I am really stuck on is how to code server side whereby the plot output is dependent on countries selected from selectInput - i.e. line graph by date and with one or more countries.

What would also be great if I could select, as well, the required data source for the graph eg df$PEOPLE_P_NEW_CASES_COUNT or df$PEOPLE_D_COUNT etc.

app code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(highcharter)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(ggplot2)

covid_1 <-
  read.csv("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/COVID-19 Activity.csv")
df <-
  data.frame(
    covid_1$REPORT_DATE,
    covid_1$PEOPLE_DEATH_NEW_COUNT,
    covid_1$PEOPLE_POSITIVE_NEW_CASES_COUNT,
    covid_1$PEOPLE_DEATH_COUNT,
    covid_1$PEOPLE_POSITIVE_CASES_COUNT,
    covid_1$COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME
  )

worldmap <- df %>%
  group_by(covid_1.COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME, covid_1$COUNTRY_ALPHA_3_CODE) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(covid_1.PEOPLE_DEATH_NEW_COUNT),
               list(deaths = sum))

ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(titleWidth = 350, title = "COVID19 - UK & World Data"),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 350,
                     sidebarMenu(
                       menuItem("World Map", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                       menuItem(
                         "Line Graph by Selection",
                         tabName = "multiselect",
                         icon = icon("dashboard")
                       )
                     )),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", br(),
              fluidRow(column(
                width = 12, plotlyOutput("World_Map", height = 600)
              ))),
      
      #Second Tab
      tabItem(
        tabName = "multiselect",
        br(),
        column(width = 8, highchartOutput("line", height = 450)),
        column(
          width = 4,
          selectInput(
            inputId = "country",
            label = "Country: ",
            multiple = TRUE,
            choices = sort(unique(df$covid_1.COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME))
          )
        )
      )
    ))
  )
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$World_Map <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      worldmap,
      type = 'choropleth',
      locations = worldmap$`covid_1$COUNTRY_ALPHA_3_CODE`,
      z = worldmap$deaths,
      text = worldmap$COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME,
      colorscale = "Reds"
    ) %>% layout(title = "<b><b>")
  })
  
  # THIS IS WHERE I WANT OUTPUT LINE GRAPH
  #
  #  Best scenario is whereby I would like a line graph where lines are represented by countries selected from Second Tab and by date df$REPORT_DATE)
  #  the data could be one of (covid_1$PEOPLE_DEATH_NEW_COUNT,covid_1$PEOPLE_POSITIVE_NEW_CASES_COUNT,covid_1$PEOPLE_DEATH_COUNT,
  #  covid_1$PEOPLE_POSITIVE_CASES_COUNT)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you provide complete app code to make this post reproducible?

Comment: The chart output does not have to be "highchartOutput" it could be any type for now eg ggplot2 . Many thanks for any help provided as this is my very first attempt at dashboard.

Comment: The post isn't reproducible if you don't share data or sample of data. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [reactive](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) version of your df that is filtered on countries each time a user selects a country from your selectInput.

This part goes into your server function

> df_reactive <- reactive({
> req(input$country)
> df <- df %>%
> filter(COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME %in% input$country)
> })

Then you can use your reactive df using df_reactive() instead of your df.

In order to be able to have a dynamic selection of variable to be rendered on your map, you could consider using some radioButtons [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/radioButtons.html) and use in a similar manner as above.

Comment: Hi ....Prompt response and  great advice - now working as hoped. Many Thanks.